# Unrecognizable USB after formatting with zeros' in Windows 10

Tags: partitioning, mount

Formatted USB in Windows 10 and after the format was complete the device couldn't be recognized anymore. I have checked many things here because Windows couldn't do anything and command `sudo fdisk -l` displays:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9a49d169

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 616941567 616939520 294,2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       616943614 625141759   8198146   3,9G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       616943616 625141759   8198144   3,9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I am new in Linux and don't know how to deal with it. Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly: you've formatted your USB hard drive, and it does no longer turn up in Windows? If that is correct, the problem is that Windows cannot read the Linux file system (ext), at least not without any third-party software. If you're going to be moving the hard drive between Linux and Windows systems often, I'd recommend formatting it to a FS that is compatible on both platforms, like NTFS.

Comment: I formatted the USB in Windows, the USB wasn't showing up so I went to try on a Linux laptop and it wasn't working too. The format was made in Fat32.

Comment: You could try `dmesg | tail` after plugging it in. It might show errors or other clues.

Comment: Ok, here is the output: dmesg | tail
[  348.958372] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[  349.021793] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlx54b80a3fe984 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:6056:49e1:8725:2991 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=40420 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24

Comment: '[  349.021832] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlx54b80a3fe984 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:6056:49e1:8725:2991 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=609566 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[  349.032030] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlx54b80a3fe984 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:6056:49e1:8725:2991 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=40420 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8612 LEN=24'

Comment: '[  349.032086] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlx54b80a3fe984 OUT= MAC= SRC=fe80:0000:0000:0000:6056:49e1:8725:2991 DST=ff02:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 LEN=64 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=1 FLOWLBL=609566 PROTO=UDP SPT=8612 DPT=8610 LEN=24 
[  349.981855] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  349.985315] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  349.986496] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  367.022612] R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
[  369.596221] R8188EU: ERROR assoc success'

Comment: These are pretty hard to read. Why don't you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/958790/edit) the question and add the outputs? For log blocks of text, there is http://pastebin.com.